# Serenity Bdd 4.1.0 : No BaseStepListener has been registered

Tags: java, maven, serenity-bdd

Getting No BaseStepListener has been registered error while trying to access the feature files example data as

`StepEventBus.getEventBus().getCurrentStep().get().getDescription()`